# C : Array, Loop, Min Element Values

Tags: c

I'm looking for help with this question:

"Create an array of 10 ints called myArray.  Give the array contents an initial value of 0 in the variable declaration.  Create a loop to prompt the user and get revised values for all of the array elements, pressing ENTER after each of the 10 items.  Within the loop, keep track of which element has the lowest value.  After the loop is done, display the minimum element's index and value."

I am a new student. The code I made doesn't work but hoping someone can see the problem or what I'm missing. The getNum variable was made by our teacher for us to use.

I need help being able to output the smallest element with the variable associated with that element.

```
int main()
{
    int getNum(void);
    int sizeArray = 10;
    int myArray[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int counter = 0;
    int smallestNumber =0;

    print("Enter 10 Integers:\n");
    for (counter = 0; counter < sizeArray; counter++)
    {
        myArray[sizeArray] = getNum();
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < sizeArray; counter++)
    {
        if(myArray[counter] < smallestNumber) {
            smallestNumber = myArray[counter];
        }
    }
    printf("Smallest number is %d, in Element %d. \n", smallestNumber, counter);
    return 0;
}

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
int getNum(void) {
    char record[121] = {0};
    int number = 0;
    fgets(record, 121, stdin);
    if( sscanf(record, "%d", &number) != 1){
        number = -1;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: *Create an array of 10 ints called myArray* - Your `myArray` is of size *one* integer.

Comment: "doesn't work" How so? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I changed the myArray to 10. @EugeneSh.

Comment: I can input 10 integers, but the code breaks there. It's not returning the lowest number and element. I'm unsure why @Yunnosch

Comment: Unless you declare `int myArray[10]` you don't have an array of 10. When you assign to anything except `myArray[0]` you're causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Then update your code and the problem description.

Comment: `myArray[sizeArray] = getNum();` - this is assigning to the last element only (which is in fact the eleventh element of the array, that is supposed to be of length ten..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited your code so I will provide the main problem with your original code for context.

You initially declared and defined your myArray as follows:

```
int myArray[] = {0};
```

As mentioned in the comments, the proper way to accomplish this is with:

```
int myArray[10] = {0};
```

Alternatively, you could have done it using a for loop as you attempted to initially with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

But, for such a simple task, the first way is much easier.

We shouldn't stop there, however.  There are some simple ways to improve your code.  Instead of hardcoding the size of the array AND having the sizeArray variable, why not do something like a define statement before your main function:

```
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10
```

This will allow you to do some useful things in your code that can be changed MUCH easier in the future:

```
int myArray[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
...
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_ARRAY; i++) {} //Note also the change to 'int i'
```

Another thing is the counter variable.  It is an additional variable that you don't need. You can just utilize the 'int i' as above in your loop. What if instead of having a counter variable AND a smallestNumber variable, you combine them into a single variable called something like this:

```
int smallestIdx = 0;
```

Then, in your for loop you could do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_ARRAY; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = getNum();
    if (myArray[i] < myArray[smallestIdx]){
    smallestIdx = i;
    }
}
```

And because you are only keeping track of the index of the smallest integer in your array, you could print like this:

```
printf("Smallest number is %d, in Element %d. \n", myArray[smallestIdx], smallestIdx);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!